# Getting this error while uploading a sketch to ESP32-Cam module

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

While following this tutorial:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-face-recognition-arduino-ide/

I am getting this error when (trying to) uploading the sketch:

```
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem14101
Connecting....
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ5 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
MAC: f4:cf:a2:9a:0d:b0
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...

A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0xF8)
A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0xF8)
```

So it seems like it is connecting in some way, but for some reason the connection gets aborted.

Can anyone point me into the right direction to resolve this issue? Can it be a hardware problem?

Comment: This can happen for so many different reasons.
Make sure there's nothing else connected to your board (no extra sensors, LEDs, etc.). Make sure that your machine recognizes the board (on Windows, I use UsbDeview for this. On Linux, lsusb should point you in the right direction.). Try lowering the upload speed. Try erasing the board first. Try forcing the board to go into "programming" mode.

Comment: How do I lower the upload speed?

Comment: It's under the "Tools" menu in the Arduino IDE.
Note that it doesn't show up until you have the board selected.